# Permutation to a power $\sigma^{100}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, solution-verification

$\sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\3&1&4&5&6&2\end{array}\right)$

I need to calculate $\sigma^{100}$

$\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$ has order 6,

and if I understand correctly, if a group element g has order n, then $g^m = g^r, r= m \,(mod \, n)$

and $ 100 \, (mod \, 6) = 4$ so $\sigma^{100} = \sigma^4$

$\sigma^4 = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\6&5&2&1&3&4\end{array}\right) = \sigma^{100}$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have it. (Sorry; I'd put this in a comment, but don't have enough rep to.)